# In the Forgotten Realms, did Mystra’s ban apply to magic used by the gods?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, magic, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

In the FR universe, before [Mystra's ban](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mystra%27s_Ban), spells up to 12th level could be cast relatively easily by mortals. It’s safe to assume the gods could do the same.

Were the gods affected by the ban on spells higher than 9th level? Could a god theoretically slice off a mountain and flip it, or seal off a crystal sphere? They were innocent in this matter, and surely if anyone could be trusted with this responsibility, it would be the gods.

Is there any reference to Mystra's ban that mentions whether such limitations were imposed on deities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Forgotten Realms lore, can gods use spells above 9th level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174058/in-forgotten-realms-lore-can-gods-use-spells-above-9th-level). "Mystra's Ban" happened between 2nd and 3rd editions...so I think the answer there is accurate (as it is sourced from 3E materials)

Comment: There is little to no indication that _anything_ short of an overdeity can seal off a crystal sphere, including spells of 10th-12th level. See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185078/4563) for more on that.

Comment: guildsbounty, no it does not. I asked that question as well, but the answer wasn’t what I wanted. Because the two answers either pointed to using high level spell slots for spells of levels 1-9, or a case of casting 10th level magic for mortals. Neither one answers if gods can cast 10th, 11th or higher level spells with ease like before the ban.

Comment: KRyan, the Netherese spell “ Proctiv's seal crystal sphere” prevented spelljamming access to a sphere, that’s what I was referring to.

Comment: FRW says "Mystra's Ban was a decree that the goddess Mystra made about the mortal use of powerful magic" but the source (LEoF p43) says "Mystra banned certain high-level spells that she deemed too powerful for mortals to wield responsibly" - this is scant proof but FRW at least interpreted the ban as only applying to mortals.

Comment: TelekeneticBarbarian, I don’t have the context behind that quote, could it be interpreted as Mystra banning all castings of such spells using the weave due to mortals messing up? Which would punish the gods who also use the weave for simplicity?